# Extraction of specific pattern using regex python

Tags: python, extract, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, feature-extraction

I wish to take a string input and extract a specific pattern:

For Example :

```
string = '''s = "STRUCTURES 9""W X 7""H 1-100W SCON"'''
```

from above string i want to extract  **9""W X 7.5""H**
how can i do it?
Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

```py
import re


string = '''s = "STRUCTURES 9""W X 7""H 1-100W SCON"'''

match = re.search('STRUCTURES (.*?H)', string).group(1)

print(match)
```

Output:

```
9""W X 7""H
```

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with [αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7658985/%CE%B1%D4%8B%C9%B1%D2%BD%D4%83-%CE%B1%D0%BC%D1%94%D1%8F%CE%B9c%CE%B1%CE%B7), but if you have multiple instances of similar words that need to be searched, you can use the `findall` function, which returns a list of all occurrences,
 for example if you want to extract :
`9""W X 7""H` and `9""W Y 8""H`, Use :

```
import re


string = '''s = ["STRUCTURES 9""W X 7""H 1-100W SCON","STRUCTURES 9""W Y 8""H 1-100W SCON"]'''

match = re.findall('STRUCTURES (.*?H)', string)

print(match)
```

Output :

```
['9""W X 7""H','9""W Y 8""H']
```

Comment: thankyou @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη  for the replies, you might have interpreted the question in wrong way but i want to extract only 'number""W X number""H' the above mentioned example is a specific use case. Hope you can help me now. Thankyou again

Comment: thankyou @Roshin Raphel for the reply, you might have interpreted the question in wrong way but i want to extract the below pattern only
 number""W X number""H
It isn't nacessary that the pattern is followed by structures.
the above mentioned example is a specific use case. Hope you can help me now. Thankyou again